# How can I maintain the constants in karate feature?

Tags: testing, karate, browser-automation

working on the browser automation using Karate and I need to check the string in some places.
Example: menu labels.
It would be really helpful if we had the option to maintain the strings in a single file and consume those values across feature files.
Currently, there are repeated strings in some places, and hard to change if the label is changed in the actual UI.

Example Code:
Then click('{span}DASHBOARD')

This dashboard string hardcoded in many places and need to define it in one place so that we can just change in one place insetad of all files.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON to manage re-usable strings: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#locator-lookup

Then you can do this:

```
* click('{span}' + dashboard)
```

That said I don't recommend this. Keep in mind that these are tests not "production code". Karate is already so simple, that creating an abstraction over it is counter-productive. You will waste time trying to look at 2 files instead of everything in one place. But of course this is just my opinion and it is completely up to you.